# An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occured by upgrading grpc to v 2.33.1 of with TargetFrameworkVersion 4.8

Tags: grpc

I am getting the exception below when i tried to upgrade grpc version to 2.33.1
TargetFrameworkVersion : 4.8

The content of this exception did not tell me any thing, can any body give any help
Thanks.

Used Package References :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.14.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core.Api" Version="2.33.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.33.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

### Message: An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred and was caught.

2021-11-05T19:00:30.966+01:00
Exception Messages:
RpcException        : Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Cancelled", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1636135230.919000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:28000","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}")

Type         : Grpc.Core.RpcException, Grpc.Core.Api, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad
Message      : Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Cancelled", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1636135230.919000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:28000","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}")
Context Messages:
Exception occurred from calling /ServiceGrpc/Init.
Source       : mscorlib
Status       : Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Cancelled", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1636135230.919000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:28000","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}")
StatusCode   : Cancelled
Trailers     : Grpc.Core.Metadata
TargetSite   : Void Throw()
Stack Trace  :    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\AsyncCall.cs:line 78 at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\DefaultCallInvoker.cs:line 46
at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core.Api\Interceptors\InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:line 51

Comment: That is a runtime exception. Your caller has sent a Cancellation trailer.

Comment: Any help would be helpful

Comment: Just giving us a stack trace is giving us less than half the story. You haven't posted any code, and you haven't posted steps to repo. What I can see is a perfectly expected exception being thrown by a server when the client has indicated that it wants to cancel the request.

Comment: In other words, this looks like gRPC behaving as documented.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.